# Tomar valor desde otra tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Les hago una consulta.

Actualmente tengo una tabla de clientes con fechas de vencimientos y costos. Una tarea cron corre en el servidor y cuando encuentra un registro que coincide en fecha envía un email al registro con el costo que debe abonar.

Ahora bien, muchos registros tienen el mismo valor de costo, por lo que cuando tengo que actualizar precios, suelo actualizar todo el valor con:

```
UPDATE `tabla` SET `costo` = replace(costo,'valor-antiguo','valor-nuevo');
```

Pero hay varios que no tienen ese precio y debo ir editándolos a mano.

Lo que necesitaría es algo que por ejemplo:

> Al cliente 1 le asigne el costo A,
>   al cliente 2 el costo B,
>   al cliente 3 el costo A,

Y así sucesivamente, cosa que después solo tenga que actualizar A y B.

No estoy muy metido en el tema de programación y el código que uso lo he hecho copiando aquí y allá de distintos ejemplos en internet e ir adaptándolo a mis necesidades. Creo que necesito otra tabla o tal vez puedo colocar esos valores en alguna columna extra de la misma tabla que ya tengo.

Les agradeceré mucho su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Podrías modificar tu pregunta para ayudarte con un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Si además incorporas la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) ya podríamos montar el ejemplo e intentar darte una solución. No olvides poner un ejemplo concreto de lo que esperas obtener. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que a la tabla `tabla` le añadas un campo `tarifa` que te permita categorizar a cada tipo de cliente, de forma que con un simple `UPDATE` puedas actualizar los precios de cada tarifa:

```
UPDATE tabla SET costo='valor-nuevo-A' WHERE tarifa='A';
UPDATE tabla SET costo='valor-nuevo-B' WHERE tarifa='B';
```

Y, ya puestos a hacerlo bien y esto ya es opcional, lo que procedería sería normalizar esa base de datos sacando el costo de `tabla` e incluyéndolo en una tabla `tarifas`, de forma que elimines esa redundancia en el costo y únicamente tengas que cambiar el costo en un único registro cuando actualices costos.

Comment: Gracias David. Por tu respuesta. Justamente me estoy manejando de esa manera: cambiando precios en masa por UPDATE, pero sucede que hay clientes que tiene combinaciones de precios, por ejemplo muchos tienen mas dos unidades de un mismo producto o tienen una unidad A y una unidad B y ahí ya se complica el UPDATE.

Me gustaria poder asignar letras o codigos a los que yo despues pueda asignarles el valor, por ejemplo:

A= $100
B= $50
C= $200
D= $150

De esa manera cambiando cuatro valores (A,B,C y D) tendría impacto en toda la tabla.

Muchas gracias desde ya.

Comment: Entonces los costos no se asignan por cliente, sino por producto. Te sugiero plantear una nueva pregunta teniendo en cuenta este nuevo enfoque. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615) con la pregunta actual.